# Oracle Apex SQL in IR to compare columns and highlight the columns with differences

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive report with following query.

```
select db_name, db_value,db_order from db_attributes;
```

I need to compare all 3 columns with another table and highlight the columns which are different.

The comparison table is:

```
select db_name, db_value,db_order from db_attributes@db_test;
```

Comment: Hint : **CASE..WHEN** expressions

Comment: Is there any column you can join these tables on? If not, you'll have to use cross join and that's really not what you'd want to look at.

Comment: So if there's a match value, lets say case when a.col1=b.col1 then 1 else 0 end match is the logic. How do i highlight a.col1 on the basis of match value? Say i want to highlight it as yellow when match =1. Hw do i do it in a DA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a way to identify a match that should be highlighted - here is an example of how to highlight a particular cell in an interactive report based on a condition in the report.

- Create interactive report on the sample emp/dept data with source

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO,
       CASE WHEN SAL >= 3000 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END MATCHED
  from EMP
```

- Give the report a Static ID of `emp`
- Create the classes: page attributes > css > insline

```
.highlight {
    background-color: #E97451;
}

#emp td:has(.highlight) {
    background-color: #E97451;
}
```

Without the 2nd class, the text background will not fill the entire cell.

- Set column MATCHED to "Hidden Column"
- Set column ENAME > Column Formatting > HTML Expression to:

```
{when Y/}
<div class="highlight">#ENAME#</div>
{otherwise/}
<div>#ENAME#</div>
{endcase/}
```

This is using [Template Directives](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/using-template-directives.html#GUID-7B407C82-7469-4C02-811C-E43380D1B73C)

- Result:

[image]